# How to hash a string into 4 digits with values above 1000 and below 9999?

Tags: python, string, hash, integer

Any method to generate a hash of some string into a 4 digit int that's `> 1000` and `<= 9999`?

Comment: Generate a hash between 0 and 8998. Then add 1001 to it.

Comment: @python_user I don't think the answers there will guarantee that the hash is above a minimum like `1000`.

Comment: Why do you need the hash to be at least 1001?

Comment: @Barmar I need to generate a random UID for Linux between `> 1000`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From barmar's idea :

```
datainput = input("Enter a string : ")
hashoutput = (hash(datainput) % 8999) + 1001
print(hashoutput)
```